# MySQL needs IP however im running it in my own computer

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, unit-testing, testing

I am performing unit testing with a full functional SMS application. I encountered this while running the unit testing.

[image: TEST ERROR]

Can anyone explain to me why i need an ip if im just using mysql in my own computer? Im plainly using localhost,root, and admin. so why do i still need an ip address like this? can anyone explain Please badly needed.

I started adding these codes before you suggested your answer

```
"CREATE user '" & txtUsername.Text & "'@'" & txtServer.Text & "' IDENTIFIED BY '" & txtPassword.Text & "';"
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '" & txtUsername.Text & "'@'" & txtServer.Text & "' identified by '" & txtPassword.Text & "' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
"CREATE user '" & txtUsername.Text & "'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '" & txtPassword.Text & "';"
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '" & txtUsername.Text & "'@'%' identified by '" & txtPassword.Text & "' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
"FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

I then came up with this problem. i dont know what to do first

[image: new test error]

Can anyone assist me please :'(

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL server is configured to only accept connections from localhost, the IP address for which should be 127.0.0.1.

Your client software is using your host's hardware network interface, the IP address for that is 192.168.8.102. This is not the same as localhost - at least it shouldn't be on a properly configured system.

You need to tell your client to use 127.0.0.1 as its IP address.

Comment: i encountered another problem again. any suggestions. badly need it